# regex not capturing correctly

Tags: regex

I have the [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/iY4vE7/2):

```
~\[(.*)\] (.*): (.*)~s
```

The desired behavior is to capture the text between `[` and `]` (the first occurrence of both). So in this case:

```
[7/25/2015 8:40:18 PM] Ghost: [Saturday, July 25, 2015 8:13 PM] Nathan: 

<<< Quoted text
```

`7/25/2015 8:40:18 PM` should be captured. However, as you can see in the regex101 example, the captured text is `7/25/2015 8:40:18 PM] Ghost: [Saturday, July 25, 2015 8:13 PM`.

I have no idea how this is happening. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `*` is greedy by default, use `*?` for a **non-greedy** match.

Comment: `*` is greedy, it'll consume everything it can. Change to: `\[([^\]])\]`

Comment: Yep that fixed it. Thanks for that :)

Comment: @mattrick please post the relevant regex here instead of linking to it

Comment: Please also add the language tag to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture the first occurrence of text inside `[...]` can be achieved with a much more simplified regex:

```
\[([^]]*)]
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xL0iA9/2)

Judging by the sample data, there cannot be any nested `[...]` sequences, and there should be no stray `]` inside the square brackets. Thus, a negated character class looks best here.

Here is what the regex means:

- `\[`- match literal `[`
- `([^]]*)` - match and capture into Group 1 0 or more characters other than `]` (note we do not have to escape `]` inside a character class at the beginning of range)
- `]` - matches a literal `]` (note again that this closing square bracket is unambiguous since there is an escaped first `[` before it).

This will match the first occurrence without `g` option, and you can get this behavior using appropriate functions/methods of your programming language.

If you need to match this first occurrence in the beginning of a string/line, use an anchor `^` (to enforce multiline mode you will need `/m` modifier):

```
^\[([^]*&^]*)]
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/xL0iA9/3)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `.*` non greedy to stop at the first match:

```
\[(.*?)\] (.*?): (.*)
```

Comment: Or, better for performance: `\[([^\]])]` (Note also that since you escaped the first `[`, no need to escape the closing one).

Answer (score 0):

This will extract the values

Sample use

```
7/25/2015 8:40:18 PM Ghost: Saturday, July 25, 2015 8:13 PM Nathan:
```

With this

```
(\d+\/\d+\/+\d+ \d+\:\d+\:\d+ [A|P]M)[^:]*: ([A-Z][a-z]+\, [A-Z][a-z]* \d+, \d+ \d+:\d+ [A|P]M)
```

Comment: He's looking to extract a very specific set of data